# cakephp Validation rules aren't holding on submit

Tags: php, cakephp

**User Model**

```
//...

public $validate = array(
    "username" => array(
        "alpha-numeric" => array(
            'rule'     => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message'  => 'Username must contain only numbers and letters.'                 
        ),
        "between" => array(
            "rule" => array("between", 4, 25),
            "message" => "Username must contain between 4 to 25 characters."
        )
    ),

//...
```

**User Controller**

```
public function index() {
    debug($this->data); // displays values as expected
    debug($this->User->validates()); // always false, unless I remove alphanumeric rule
}
```

On submit, my form will always validate the `username` field as false (triggering its corresponding message), no matter what is in the text. The remaining fields are also not validated. If I remove the `username` validation rules all together, the remaining fields are still not validated. (Form is submitted as though validated)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before manually calling `$this->User->validates()`, you must call the model's `set` method and provide the form's data.

```
public function index() {
    $this->User->set($this->request->data); // Only way the next method will work.
    debug($this->User->validates());
}
```

Comment: also, validates() only returns true/false. for more information on the validation errors themselves, see the content of `$this->User->validationErrors` afterwards.